# Limits and metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g$ be functions from $(X,\rho) \to \mathbb{R}$. Show that if $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x)$ exist, and there exists $\delta > 0$, such that for every $x \in \mathcal{B}_{\delta}(x_0) \setminus \{x_0\}$ we have $$f(x) \leq g(x)$$ then $$\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) \leq \lim_{x \to x_0}g(x)$$

---

So restating the problem, it says if $f \leq g$ always for all points sufficiently close to $x_0$, then $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) \leq \lim_{x \to x_0}g(x)$. I was thinking of doing this by contradiction, but didn't really know how to start off. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: here's something similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287986/if-fxgx-prove-that-lim-fx-lim-gx

Comment: Oh, that is good. Thanks

Comment: you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L = \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ and $M = \lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)$. Suppose, to the contrary, that $L > M$. Then $\varepsilon := \frac{L-M}{2} > 0$. Since $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L$, there exists a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that for all $x$, $0 < \rho(x,x_0) < \delta_1$ implies $f(x) > L - \varepsilon = \frac{M+L}{2}$. Since $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x) = M$, there exists a $\delta_2 > 0$ such that for all $x$, $0 < \rho(x,x_0) < \delta_2$ implies $g(x) < M + \varepsilon = \frac{M+L}{2}$. Let $\delta = \min\{\delta,\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. Choose an $x$ such that $0 < \rho(x,x_0) < \delta$. Then $f(x) > \frac{M+L}{2} > g(x)$, which contradicts the assumption that $f(x) \le g(x)$ whenever $0 < \rho(x,x_0) < \delta$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for me to delete my 'answer', so I will instead edit it as this. I had thought I had solved the problem, but did not.