# if $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x$ and $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ exist on $a$, then $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) < \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$?

Tags: limits

It might be a duplicate of this
[If $f(x)<g(x)$ prove that $\lim f(x)<\lim g(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287986/if-fxgx-prove-that-lim-fx-lim-gx)

But it's kinda different as $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ exists on $a$.

''
if $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x$ and $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ exist on $a$, then $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) < \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$?
''

I can't think of any counter example, but I'm neither able to prove it.
I'm a newbie in math.Please help!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are examples already in the page that you linked.

Comment: Consider $a=0$, $f(x)=x^2$ for $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=1$, $g(x)=0$. The assumptions are satisfied, but $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0=\lim_{x\to0}g(x)$. I don't see anything different from the linked question.